# Getting a Server's encoding using Java

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, decode, encode

Is it possible to programmatically get the encoding scheme used by, say Tomcat, to decode a GET parameter?

I know you can force Tomcat to use specific encodings, but this is for when i can't control the Tomcat settings.  I'm thinking of getting the correct encoding by either parsing the query string myself, or trying to re-encode the value using whatever Tomcat did to decode it, and then decoding it with UTF-8 to get the correct string.

Answer (score 1):

From http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp, the URL encoding is ASCII and the rules for special characters can easily be reversed. Parameters in GET are URL encoded.

If you are talking about the value in GET itself, then, your question does not really makes sense (or I misunderstand you), since you will obtain a string in your Java servlet. The parameter will already be decoded. You don't need to worry about the encoding.

Comment: I know I can parse it myself.  I'd rather see if it can be done "automatically".

The problem lies in that the decoded value is wrong, since it uses ISO-8859-1 instead of UTF-8 and I might not have control of the server settings in order to enforce UTF-8 decoding by the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can always try to perform [`getCharacterEncoding`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getCharacterEncoding%28%29). There is though one guarantee. If the URIEncoding attribute has not been altered in the `server.xml` you can always assume ISO-8859-1. If you get the string with `getParameter`, retrieve the raw bytes and construct a new string with UTF-8 encoding. URLs are always escaped as UTF-8 text.